# Total number of results and limit in active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, pagination

I am fetching some of the listings from the DB and displaying it in a paginated screens. But for the pagination, I need to take the total count of results. I am using Codeigniter and ActiveRecords. My query is something like this  :

```
$query = $this->db->select('sum(amount) as sum')
              ->where(date_added between '$from' and '$to')
              ->group_by('date_added')
              ->get('my_table');
```

I need to run this query with and without the limits for getting total number of values and to get the paginated output with limits. Now I need to copy the query again and run it with the limits. Is there any other way so that I can copy the complete query object to another variable and call the get again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for active record caching
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching

```
public function cache_query() {

$this->db->start_cache();
$this->db->select('sum(amount) as sum')
              ->where(date_added between '$from' and '$to')
              ->group_by('date_added');
$this->db->stop_cache();
}

public function get_query() {

$this->build_query();
$query = $this->db->get('my_table');
$this->db->flush_cache();

}

public function count_query() {
$this->build_query();
$query = $this->db->count_all('my_table');
$this->db->flush_cache();
}
```

Comment: Wow this is working. I have been looking for something like this for a long time. Thanks David :)

Comment: For sure. Thanks for letting me know you solved your problem. That matters more than the points

Answer (score 1):

One way you can use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in you select query with i limit also the you need to run `FOUND_ROWS()` that will give the count of all rows without a limit

```
$query = $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS sum(amount) as sum')
              ->where(date_added between '$from' and '$to')
              ->group_by('date_added')
              ->get('my_table')
              ->limit($perpage, $start);
```

Then you need to get count

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `count`');
echo  $query->row()->count;
```

[**FOUND_ROWS()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: I suggest you as for performance its better to have the limited results and the count of total results in one query rather than running query again to fine the count and for speed up you need main the standards of mysql by assigning the proper data types to the columns , proper indexes for the fields usually used in where clause

Comment: yeah. just read here like this can be 10X slower than running the two quries in some cases http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Answer (score 0):

try like this
In your controller

```
function yourFunction()
{
$total_rows=$this->modal_name->function_name()->num_rows();
$this->db->limit(1,20); // set you limit here
$rows=$this->modal_name->function_name()->result_array();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
you use to limit.
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. It is not how to apply the limit. It is how can I use the same query again and again and its already answered.